# Need help extracting specific lines from a changing logfile using expect

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to use an expect script to access a remote device via telnet, read/save the remote "EVENTLOG" locally, and then extract specific lines (serial numbers) from the log file.  Problem is the log files are constantly changing so I need a way to search for specific strings.  The remote device is Linux based, but doesn't have things like grep, vi, less, etc as it's QNX Neutrino, hence having to do it locally.

I've successfully gotten the telnet, read the file and save locally under control, but when I get to "reading" the file is when I have issues.  Currently I'm just trying to get it to print what it found, but the script just exits without reporting anything except some extra braces??

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
    log_user 1

    spawn telnet $IP
    match_max 100000
    expect "login:"
    send -- "$USER\r"
    expect "Password:"
    send -- "$PW\r"
    expect "# "
    send -- "\r"

#at this point logged into device
#send command to generate the "dallaslog"

    set dallaslog [open dallaslog.txt w]
    expect "#" 
        send -- "cat `ls -rt /LOG/event*`\r"

    expect "(cat) exited status=0"
    set logout $expect_out(buffer)
    puts $dallaslog "$logout"
    close $dallaslog
    unset expect_out(buffer)

    set dallasread [open dallaslog.txt r]
    set lines [split [read $dallasread] "\r"]
    close $dallasread

    puts "${green}$lines{$normal}"
#a debug line to print $dallasread in green so I can verify it works up to here

    foreach line $lines {
        if {[regexp {.*Dallas ID: 0.*\n} $lines match]} {
        if {$match == 1} {
            puts $line  ;# Prints whole line which has 1 at end 
        }
        }
    }
    expect "# "
    send -- "exit\r"
    interact
```

What I'm (eventually) looking for is the script to catch any line starting with "Dallas ID:" and then to save that information to a variable, so I can use the "scan" command to parse the line and extract information.

What I get is:

```
(the results from $lines being "puts" in green)
"...
<ENTRY TIME="01/01/1970 00:48:07" PROC="syncd" FILE="mips.cc" LINE="208" NUM="10000">
UTC step from 01/01/1970 00:48:08 to 01/01/1970 00:48:07
</ENTRY>

Process 3174431 (cat) exited status=0
}{}
# exit

Process 3162142 (sh) exited status=0.
Connection closed by foreign host."
```

Thank you in advance for all the help.  I'm a newbie to TCL/expect (been toying with it since last July) but I'm finding it to be a pretty powerful tool, just hard for me to debug!

EDIT: Added more information per @meuh 's reponse.
Example:  There can be up to 4 Dallas ID, but generally I only have 0 and 1.  Goal is to get the SN, BC, CN for reach Dallas ID saved as variables to put in a separate text file.

```
<ENTRY TIME="01/01/1970 00:00:06" PROC="sys" FILE="PlatformUtils.cpp" LINE="1227" NUM="10044">
Dallas ID: 1 SN:00000622393A BC: J4AD945 CN: IS200BPPBH2BMD R0: 001C 
</ENTRY>
```

The foreach loop I used was an example from an old question on stack overflow I tried to modify to use here, unsuccessfully.

EDIT:  I should also probably mention that this event log is approximately 800 lines long every time it gets read, which is why I haven't posted an excerpt from it.

Comment: You might want to use the `log_file dallaslog.txt` expect command instead of manually capturing the output and writing to a file

Comment: @glennjackman I tried your suggestion, using the command `log_file -noappend dallaslog.txt` but then the script seems like it can't open the dallaslog.txt file because my `puts $lines` command has no output anymore

Comment: You can turn off logging once the `cat` command completes:use `log_file` with no arguments.

Comment: An interesting discovery: if I use the `log_file` command and then set `log_user 0` to hide console output, the variables in the log become undefined.  However, if I manually capture the output (even with console output disabled) it all works just fine.  Unless I use the `-a` command!  Excellent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regexp line is probably not doing what you want:

```
if {[regexp {.*Dallas ID: 0.*\n} $lines match]} {
    if {$match == 1} {
        puts $line
```

You are passing the list `$lines` instead of, presumably, the single line `$line`. The variable `match` will be set to the string that matched which must therefore include the words "Dallas" and so on, so it can never be 1.
Your code comment says *Prints whole line which has 1 at end*, but I'm not sure what you are looking for as you do not have any example data that fits the regexp.

If you choose your regexp pattern using grouping you could capture parts of the line so perhaps not need a further `scan`. Eg

```
regexp {PROC="([a-z]*)"} $line match submatch
```

would set variable submatch to `syncd` in your above example.

---

You may also have a fundamental problem caused by tcl's handling of `\r\n` on input from a file. The lines you got from `$expect_out(buffer)` do indeed have the 2 characters as end-of-line delimiters. However,
when using `read`, by default I believe, it will translate the same sequence to a normalised `\n`. So your split will not do anything, and you need to split on `\n` rather than `\r`.  You can check the size of the list of lines you have with

```
puts [llength $lines]
```

If it is 1, then your split is not working. Replace it with

```
set lines [split [read $dallasread] "\n"]
```

This should help your loop, where for example you can try

```
foreach line $lines {
    if {[regexp {.*Dallas ID: (\d+) SN:([^ ]+)} $line match idnum SN]} {
        puts $line
        puts "$idnum, $SN"
    }
}
```

You must remove the `\n` at the end of your regexp, as this is no longer present after the split. I've extended the regexp example with `(\d+)` to match for the id number (`\d` matches a digit), and `([^ ]+)` to match any number of non-space characters after the text `SN:`.

These values are captured by the use of `()` grouping, and are placed in the variables idnum and SN, which you should be able to see output by the second `puts` command.

Comment: Perhaps my regexp is just not quite right then!  When I use your example, I actually get `sys` as the result since it stops at the first iteration.  If I use the `-all` operand, _then_ i get `syncd` since that gives the last match only.  If I try to use my regexp, I still get no output.  Perhaps my edits will shed some light on the situation!

Comment: I've added a second part to my answer. You need to check that your `split` is actually giving you a list and not just one very long string. This will break your later attempts to parse each line. I've given an example of a longer regexp you can work from.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I had toyed with the `\r` and `\n` several times and had taken steps closer/further away, but the way you explained it helps a lot!  Not only that, your regexp allowed me to see what I was doing wrong; treating regexp as a "simple search" tool, rather than using more of its potential!